# Problems with rotation in a TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

My problem is that I want to rotate a `TextView` inside a `FrameLayout`, but I cannot rotate the `FrameLayout`.

When I rotate in 90 degree the `TextView`, Its doesn't match parent!
But I need to text fill all the parent!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/FLback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FLitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVitem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:text="TEXT"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Here a example of what is the problem:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuzZZ.jpg

The problem in one pic!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Android firstly will measure view and only then will rotate it. So, I suppose you should still rotate your text view, but if you want a nice background - you should set background for a parent view.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/FLback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FLitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVitem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:text="TEXT"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The problem are not the background, but the text! It will have a small area when rotate.

Comment: so, u should, measure and layout text with another bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help!

The solution I found were measure the whole view and change the size of the Textview!

Thanks!